# Render webpages in Ubuntu font

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I love the default font in this OS. Is there any way to make my Chrome webpages load in that same font? I tried setting the font to 'Ubuntu' in the Chrome customization settings but the webpages don't seem to render in the OS font. The ask Ubuntu pages though, always load in this font (even before I changed in Chrome settings). Why not other pages?

Comment: Can you give an example of a page that doesn't match? Sometimes designers make it so certain pieces of text are locked to certain fonts, so they match the design of the site.

Comment: Like in a google search page, the font is somewhat changing I guess, but its not just the same, the one on this website. Maybe the 'Ubuntu' font Chrome has in its settings is different than the actual OS font.

Comment: Well I can tell you that Google has its font locked to Arial Sans-Serif. If you want to see where you can get, try this extension, which is supposed to force the font of your choice onto every website you visit: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E5%BC%BA%E5%88%B6%E7%BD%91%E9%A1%B5%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee?hl=en

Comment: This extension is exactly what I wanted. Now everything on every page has the Ubuntu font. Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Zacharee in the comment above the chrome extension 'Force custom fonts' does the job of changing the font on every webpage as you like and works better than the inbuilt chrome customization font setting.